# Automatic Table of Contents in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, table-of-contents

I want to make an automatic Table of Contents in a Word 2013 document, but I want to use something other than the cover page title in the Table of Contents.

For example, on page 1 there is cover page having the title "Computer Science".  But in the TOC, instead of that title, I want to write "Cover Page", automatically.

Is it possible?

[image: here is picture]

Comment: If you don't have the words `Cover Page` in your document, you won't get it in your TOC unless you write them down manually. Or you do have these words?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can insert a TC field. First, if your title is currently in Heading 1 style, as it appears from the picture you provided, you'll want to change it something else that won't automatically show up in the TOC; Title is a good choice, since it's your title, but you could also use TOC Heading which is based on Heading 1 and usually looks just like it.

Next, place the cursor next to the title text (before or after: it doesn't matter), and then press Alt+Shift+O (that's the letter O, not a zero). In the **Mark Table of Contents Entry** dialog box, in the **Entry** field, type **Cover page**. You want the entry to be at the same level as your Heading 1 paragraphs, so leave **Level** set to **1**.

Finally, you'll have to define your own custom Table of contents. On the **References** tab, click **Table of Contents** > **Custom Table of Contents**. You can set the settings in the main dialog box as you prefer. The important thing, though, is to click **Options**, and then make sure that **Table entry fields** is selected.